# How to start and stop animation.FuncAnimation by pressing a button?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to python programming, so sorry if it's a stupid question.

I am using python, matplotlib and tkinter to plot a live graph of data in a tkinter gui. Therefore I followed the tutorial of this link: https://pythonprogramming.net/plotting-live-bitcoin-price-data-tkinter-matplotlib/

Here, the animation function is used, to plot the data. I would like to start and stop this animationFunc by pressing a button on the gui, but don't know how to realize it.

I would be grateful for any kind of help!
Thanks

Here is the code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, 
NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style 
import serial
import sys

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM3', baudrate = 19200, bytesize=8, parity='N', 
stopbits=1, timeout=None,rtscts=0)

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)
style.use('ggplot')
f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi = 100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)
yList = []

def animate(i):
    # I receive data as a string with a hex number, so here I read it, take 
    #the number and append it to the yList
    r = ser.readline()
    he = r.split(" ")[2]
    g = int(he,16)
    d = str(g)
    yList.append(g)
    a.clear()
    a.plot(yList)

class Sensors(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs ):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill = "both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (ChooseSensor, Sensor3):   
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(ChooseSensor)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    #here I want to define the function to stop the animate function and to 
    #stop the serial port
    def stopPlot(event,cont):
        #command to serial port to stop sensor        
        ser.write(b'S1,P,0\r\n')

    #here i want to create the function to start the animate function
    def animate_start(self,cont):   
        #command to configure and start sensor
        ser.write(b'S1,S,2\r\n')
        ser.write(b'S1,T,1\r\n')
        ser.write(b'S1,P,1\r\n')

class ChooseSensor(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Choose Sensor", font= LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self,text="Graph Page",
                        command=lambda:controller.show_frame(Sensor3))
        button1.pack()

class Sensor3(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Graph Page", font= LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self,text="Start Plot",
                        command=lambda:controller.animate_start(self))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self,text="Stop Plot",
                        command=lambda:controller.stopPlot(self))
        button2.pack()

        button3 = tk.Button(self,text="Back to Home",
                        command=lambda:controller.show_frame(ChooseSensor))
        button3.pack()

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True)

app = Sensors()
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f,animate, interval=1000)
app.mainloop()
```

EDIT:
I tried to do something like this:

```
def animate_start(self,cont):
    global anim_start
    anim_start=True
    #Konfiguriert und schreibt Sensor1
    ser.write(b'S1,S,2\r\n')
    ser.write(b'S1,T,1\r\n')
    ser.write(b'S1,P,1\r\n')
    return anim_start

def stopPlot(event,cont):
    anim_start=False
    ser.write(b'S1,P,0\r\n')
    return anim_start
```

And then execute the animation function only, when anim_start == True:

```
app = Sensors()
if anim_start == True:
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f,animate, interval=1000)
app.mainloop()
```

Now I can see, that the commands are send and data is received (LED lights at the USB Serial bridge blink), but there is no data added to the yList anymore and so no graph is plotted

Comment: Share us what you did (code), as it would give more insight to the problem.